# Strange xcode issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

My production certificates expired yesterday so I generated new ones with new provisioning profiles. After that I got strange errors, I can build my project but can't run it in xcode (5.1.1) nor in Finder:

[image]

Also I found these errors in system.log:

```
21/06/14 11:33:23,825 taskgated-helper[8005]: Starting taskgated-helper
21/06/14 11:33:23,901 taskgated-helper[8005]: embedded provisioning profile not valid: file:///Users/Andron/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXXXX-bglqrxjbzqchjedxfyajqmqqeqeu/Build/Products/Release/XXXXXXXXXXX.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile
21/06/14 11:33:23,901 taskgated-helper[8005]: returning 3 provisioning profiles
21/06/14 11:33:23,901 taskgated-helper[8005]: unsatisfied entitlement com.apple.developer.team-identifier
21/06/14 11:33:23,901 taskgated-helper[8005]: none of the 3 applicable provisioning profile(s) apply
21/06/14 11:33:23,901 taskgated-helper[8005]: killed com.XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX[pid 8004] because its use of the com.apple.developer.team-identifier entitlement is not allowed
21/06/14 11:33:23,901 taskgated-helper[8005]: CPValidateProvisioningDictionaries returning NO with error: (null)
21/06/14 11:33:23,902 taskgated[13]: killed com.XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX[pid 8004] because its use of the com.apple.developer.team-identifier entitlement is not allowed (error code -67050)
21/06/14 11:33:23,930 ReportCrash[8007]: Attempting to read data: Called memoryAtAddress: 0x7fff5fc27816, which is in an unmappable portion of [0x0 -> 0xffffffffffffffff] in PID# 8004.
21/06/14 11:33:23,969 ReportCrash[8007]: Trying to extract VM information using cr2
21/06/14 11:33:23,971 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[177]: (com.XXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.104224[8004]) Exited: Killed: 9
21/06/14 11:33:24,138 ReportCrash[8007]: Saved crash report for XXXXXXXXXXX[8004] version ??? to /Users/Andron/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/XXXXXXXXXXX_2014-06-21-113324_Androns-MacBook-Pro.crash
```

I tried to restart my mac, clean and build the project, re-generate provisioning profiles, reset xcode settings. How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got answer from Apple: distribution builds of Mac apps cannot be run directly anymore.
Instead, developers should adopt the Archive Build Workflow in [QA1778: How to reproduce bugs reported against Mac App Store submissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1778/) for testing the builds that they plan to submit for the Mac App Store.

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue.Can you please explain me how did you get this solved ? I couldn't understand Thanks in advance !

Comment: I get the following error when I run the app from Applications folder..http://shravanit.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/macsystemerrorlog/ Can you gimme some clues ?

Comment: Hi! You should use a development provisioning profile when you build your app or export it from the Xcode Organizer. Distribution provisioning profiles can be used only for submitting to iTunes Connect.

Comment: The above error came for development provisioning profile.

Comment: Yes, I got the same error with development provisioning profile. But it works with development signing identity.

Comment: Looking at the QA1778 link ( and androns "export it from XCode organizer" comment), it mentions to "Export as Application" and select the "Developer Profile". Apparently this is not possible anymore in XCode 6(.3.1) since I can only select an export-location on disk.